# Cake PHP model validation not displaying in my view

Tags: cakephp

I am using cake PHP for integrating my stuff; however it is not showing model validation errors in my view.I think some small think is missed from my code, but didn't find out.
     Below is my model, view and controller code:

```
 Model:
 class Category extends Model {

    var $validate = array(
      'title' => array(
          'rule' => 'notEmpty',
          'message' => 'Title is required'
       )
    );
 }



 View:
 <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create( 'Category', array( 'action'=>'add', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ) );
?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add new category</legend>
        <?php           
            echo $this->Form->input( 'title' );         
        ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->submit( 'Add Category' ); 
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>

 Controller:
 class CategoriesController extends AppController { 
    var $helpers = array( 'Form', 'Html', 'Js' );   
    function add() {        
        $this->loadModel('Category');
        $this->Category->set( $this->data );
        $this->Category->save( $this->data );                       
        if( !$this->Category->validates() ){
             $errors = $this->Category->validationErrors;                
        }           
    }
 }

 Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if( !$this->Category->save( $this->data ) ){
         $errors = $this->Category->validationErrors;                
    }
```

You just check wether data has been saved or not. If not then process validation errors. Set errors to the view or just debug in the controller itself.
this may help you.

Comment: While [one line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) are acceptable, they often result in the answer being routed to the Review Queue (*q.v.*). In addition, sometimes they are not well received by the community. Its usually a good idea to provide a brief explanation that explains how the answer solves the problem.